# Text sitting outside of parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The css for the following https://codepen.io/centem/pen/GQVGmw states for text to be centered but the text is sitting to the lower right of the parent div and some of the text falls out of the div. How do I center the text to be in the middle of the parent div? Thank you.

```
            <div class="row">
              <div id="86" class="square">hostname</div>
              <div id="87" class="square">hostname</div>
              <div id="88" class="square">hostname</div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-md-4 .row div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    color: green;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: you don't have the needed space that's why

Comment: Of course the text only starts at that position - you made the first 30 px from the top and from the left unavailable, by specifying that as _padding_. // Downvote and close-as-too-broad from me, because centering stuff in CSS in all possible ways is a topic that has been discussed to death multiple times over already.

Comment: "content must be placed within columns and ***only columns*** may be immediate children of **rows**"

Answer (score 2):

It's because `padding: 30px;` , Remove padding . Also add `word-wrap: break-word;` to avoid `outside text(overlaping)`.

```
.col-md-4 .row div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    color: green;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change with it

```
.col-md-4 .row div {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 10px;
        background-color: black;
        color: green;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tHIS should work remove padding and give actual height width

    .col-md-4 .row div {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 10px;
        background-color: black;
        color: green;
        padding: 0;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        text-align: center;
        LINE-HEIGHT: 60PX;
    }
```